# Compiled Sass placing } at end of last line

Tags: css, compilation, sass

I have only just started using Sass this morning, after reading about it last night. I think I'm understanding it (but feel free to to comment if you disagree). I've ran into one problem though, be it minor but inducing an OCD head ache.

```
ul#primary-nav {
  font: 400 16px $font-stack;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 15px;
    &:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    &:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }

  a {
    color: $grey;
    padding: 10px 5px 15px 5px;
    &:hover {
      border-bottom: $blue solid 6px;
      .active {
        font-weight: 700;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This outputs the following code:

```
ul#primary-nav {
  font: 400 16px "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center; }

ul#primary-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px; }

ul#primary-nav li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0; }

ul#primary-nav li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0; }

ul#primary-nav li a {
  color: #777777;
  padding: 10px 5px 15px 5px; }

ul#primary-nav li a:hover {
  border-bottom: #25aae1 solid 6px; }

ul#primary-nav li a.active {
  border-bottom: #25aae1 solid 6px;
  font-weight: 700; }
```

So the code itself is fine for what I want but I was wondering why it is adding the closing paragraph tag to the last line. Is there a way to force it on the line below

```
ul#primary-nav li a:hover {
  border-bottom: #25aae1 solid 6px;
}
```

I know it's only a small thing but it would make me ever so happy.

Comment: What are you using to compile the SCSS? Command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is entirely possible to satisfy your OCD needs: basically you need to make sure the compiler is outputting in `expanded` style.

From [the docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_10):

**Nested**

```
#main {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000; }
  #main p {
    width: 10em; }
```

**Expanded**

```
#main {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
#main p {
  width: 10em;
}
```

From the command do this with `sass style.css --style expanded`, but your build system might also expose the option somewhere - check its docs.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. It's CodeKit I am using, a completely new venture for me but I'm enjoying it :)